# Style not working on specific google account

Tags: css, ejs, mime

I'm currently using express to run the server with ejs views and added styles to public (with express.static )

however the styling is not working but only for one google account only, as you can see on the image styling is not working but on one account but working on the others , but it says refused mime etc and i checked online mostly because of wrong stating the css path but i think thats not the case with mine cause it works on other google account and on firefox as well

ive tried resetting cache , clear browsing data etc still not working , and i can load the styles with other computer with same account , so any ideas on this behavior?
[image]

Comment: Try without the second forward slash? There is an error in your browser console that is yelling at you

Comment: stylesheet mime type is `text/css` btw

Comment: Damn ur right its only a matter of that forward slash , terribly sorry for this , its just the autocomplete and i didnt notice the forward slash 

tried changing the stylesheet to text/css before posting this question and it made the styling not working on both account tho 

thankyou for the fix

Answer (score 0):

as @Zach Jensz said on the comment its just a matter of the forward slash , tried  localhost:3000/about and the styling works , terribly sorry for such stupid question